# Restored fragment from another doesn't show

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app where the `MainActivity` have a bottom tabBar and a fragmentContainer(`FrameLayout`), when the user clicks in a button from the bottm bar I use the `FragmentManager` for replace the current showing fragment. In one of those fragments I have another tabBar(on Top) and other fragmentContainer(with another id). In the system dev options I have checked the option for immediately destroy activities. I'm using `onSaveInstanceState` and `getFragmentManager().putFragment()` for save fragments states, current tab and user input data. When user press the home button and then opens the app again, the main fragment is restored with no problems, but when should restore de inner fragment, it doesn't shows, just doesn't show, but is correctly added even the user input data. Before restore state I have no issues with replace fragments. I need some help :(

**UPDATE**

My code looks like some like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

int tabId = 0;
final View.OnClickListener tabController = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View tab) {
        if (tab.getId() == tabId) return;
        tabId = tab.getId();
        if (tabId == R.id.tab1) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new Fragment1()).commit();
        } else if (tabId == R.id.tab2) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new FragmentWhitTopBar()).commit();
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    /*  SetingUp activity views */

    tab1.setOnClickListener(tabController);
    tab2.setOnClickListener(tabController);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        this.tabId = savedInstanceState.getInt(CURRENT_TAB);
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, FRAGMENT_TAB);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
        /* All OK Yay!!! */
    } else {
        tabController.onClick(tabTransfer);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(CURRENT_TAB, tabId);
    if (shouldSaveInstanceState) {
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
        if (fragment != null)
            getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, FRAGMENT_TAB, fragment);
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
}

public class FragmentWhitTopBar extends Fragment{

int tabId = 0;
final View.OnClickListener tabController = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View tab) {
        if (tab.getId() == tabId) return;
        tabId = tab.getId();
        if (tabId == R.id.topTab1) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new Fragment2()).commit();
        } else if (tabId == R.id.topTab2) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new Fragment3()).commit();
        }
    }
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_with_top_bar, container, false);

    /*  SetingUp fragment views */

    topTab1.setOnClickListener(tabController);
    topTab2.setOnClickListener(tabController);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        this.tabId = savedInstanceState.getInt(CURRENT_TOP_TAB);
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, FRAGMENT_TOP_TAB);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
        /* Working but Not Showing D: !!! */
    } else {
        tabController.onClick(tabTransfer);
    }
    return root;
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(CURRENT_TOP_TAB, tabId);
    if (shouldSaveInstanceState) {
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
        if (fragment != null)
            getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, FRAGMENT_TOP_TAB, fragment);
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
}
```

Comment: If you are using fragment within a fragment, then for the nested fragment use childFragmentManager.

Comment: Thanks you so much. It was all... :D. You save my life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Fragment` within a `Fragment`, then for the nested fragment use `getChildFragmentManager()`.